# Why such a huge drop in new visits?

Tags: discussion

See this graph:

[image]

Comment: could you share the date ranges and other details to reproduce this (are you doing weekly average)? I'm actually not seeing it

Comment: I took the screenshot 8 minutes ago, starting from when we launched into public beta.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, I see it now. Weirdly enough, the drop doesn't seem to be mirrored by a proportionally large drop in page views, overall visits, or number of posts. Maybe they changed the way they count new visits?

Comment: @glS yea something seems extremely off, especially since this graph is telling us that it's not just the latest weekly data point, but the previous one as well! However "overall visits" and "number of posts" have also gone down lately, just not as profoundly as "new visits" have.

Comment: seems to be happening also on physics. See https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61223947#61223947

Comment: Relevant MSE question: [Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/335251)

Answer (score 6):

Educated guess, by no means official:

> We are committing to recategorizing the Google Analytics cookie as a “Performance Cookie” by May 13, 2022.

(source: [this answer by staff member @CesarM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378440/295232) - the actual switch happened on [May 10th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit/378440#comment1264074_378440))

The [site analytics](/site-analytics) are powered by Google Analytics, and if users don't accept the cookies, they don't get registered as new visits.